# Silverlight 4 User controls & mvvm

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, controls

I am migrating/rewriting a SL4 project using  the MVVM pattern. The trouble I'm having is that I have some user controls that interact only with other user controls(no connection to the Model). Where to I implement the code behind functions for this controls?

Comment: could you provide more context? or a snippet of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options. If the controls have a natural hierarchy (such as one is the other's parent) consider wrapping them into a user control and leveraging RoutedEvents.

If they are sibling controls and there is a natural parent for them, group them into a parental user control and create a viewmodel for that control that handles interaction.

If the controls are in totally separate areas on the UI, consider using [EventAggregator](http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2008/08/22/firing-generic-events-with-eventaggregator/) to have the controls fire and respond to each others messages.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mvvm pattern just use behaviours insteed of writing the code in the code behind files. 
start learning behaviours

http://www.nikhilk.net/Silverlight-Behaviors.aspx
http://wildermuth.com/2009/05/16/Writing_Behaviors_for_Silverlight_3_-_Part_1
http://joel.neubeck.net/2009/07/silverlight-3-drag-behavior/